# Joomla! Custom Modules

Tags: php, joomla, module

I'm very new to Joomla! and I'm building a custom module. I've looked at the documentation and although there is a tutorial for creating custom modules:

https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Creating_a_simple_module/Developing_a_Basic_Module

...there's no instruction for how to actually use these files, or where to put them, or how to properly install them! I've created all 4 files (3 .php, 1 .xml) and I tried putting them in the same folder structure and location as the other "stock" modules (administrator / modules / mod_helloworld etc.) but the module doesn't show up as an option when creating a new module in the back end. I also tried zipping the group of files and installing through extension manager and that didn't work either.

Perhaps I'm coming at this all wrong? This just seems to be something that is assumed knowledge in the Joomla documentation tutorial. Are there other files that need to be created? Or edits need to be made to existing files?

I'm using Joomla! 3.4.1 and am working on it from a server. I apologize in advance for what seems like a very stupid question.

Comment: If you are still stuck try [joomla.se].

Answer (score 1):

Once you have created your test module files you can put them in a folder that will have the **same name** as the one you used for your module in the XML file.
The Joomla naming convention is to start with mod_ for modules.
Let's say the module name is mod_myfirst_module in the XML file

```
<name>mod_myfirst_module</name>
```

The install folder must use the same name.
To install it you have two options:

1. For testing you can upload the files directly to the modules folder of your Joomla site (frontend modules go into modules folder, backend modules go into administrator/modules folder) and use the Discover functionality in the Extension Manager of Joomla administation backend. 
   Menu Extensions->Extension Manager-> Discover on the left column. 
   Click on the button Discover and your module will show in the list if you have properly set the files.
2. You can create an installer package. Zip the folder you previously created with the module files, go to Joomla administation backend. 
    Menu Extensions->Extension Manager->Install on the left column
    Click on Upload Package file tab and select the Zip archive you created. If the archive contains all the files needed, the module will be installed.

Answer (score 0):

Delete mod_helloworld from administrator/modules and then
.zip this and instal using Extensions>Instalator in Joomla admin panel.

If it will not work, paste the error here.